# How to access variables from foreign models in django

Tags: unit-testing, python-3.x, django-models, upload, foreign-keys

I just started out django and python so bear with me. (Just a newbie)
I have 3 models Programme, Module and Lecture.
Programme has a variable 'code' which is a foreign key to module.
Module has in turn also a variable 'code' which is a foreign key to lecture.

In lecture I have implemented a function to get dynamic path for uploading files based on the 'code' of programme, 'code' of module and 'title' of lecture.

Here is a snippet of my models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Programme(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=120)
    synopsis = models.TextField(blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def get_programme_code(self):
        return self.code

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Module(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    programme = models.ForeignKey(Programme, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=120)
    synopsis = models.TextField(blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def get_module_code(self):
        return self.code

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Lecture(models.Model):

    def get_upload_to(self):
        return 'uploads/%s/%s/%s/%s' % (Programme().get_programme_code(),Module().get_module_code,self.title,filename)

    title = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    module = models.ForeignKey(Module, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lecture_pdf = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_to)
    lecture_video = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_to)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I know that there is something wrong with my code by the way of accessing 'code's from programme and modules but I cannot figure it out.

And here is a snippet of my unit testing of the models.

```
   from django.test import TestCase
    from module_content.models import Programme, Module, Lecture
    from django.utils import timezone
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

    class ProgrammeTest(TestCase):

        def create_programme(self, code="E318", title="Computer Science",       synopsis="Englobes all computer related fields"):
            return Programme.objects.create(code =code, title=title, synopsis=synopsis, pub_date=timezone.now())

        def test_programme_creation(self):
            t = self.create_programme()
            self.assertTrue(isinstance(t, Programme))
            self.assertEqual(t.__str__(), t.title)

        def test_get_programme_code(self):
            t = self.create_programme()
            self.assertEqual(t.get_programme_code(), t.code)


    class ModuleTest(TestCase):

        def create_module(self, code="CSE2233", title="Computer Networks", synopsis="About data transmission"):
            v = ProgrammeTest().create_programme()
            return Module.objects.create(code=code, programme=v, title=title, synopsis=synopsis, pub_date=timezone.now())

        def test_module_creation(self):
            t = self.create_module()
            self.assertTrue(isinstance(t, Module))
            self.assertEqual(t.__str__(), t.title)


    class LectureTest(TestCase):

        def create_lecture(self, title="Lecture 1"):
            t = ModuleTest().create_module()
            return Lecture.objects.create(title=title, module=t)

        def test_lecture_creation(self):
            s = self.create_lecture()
            self.assertTrue(isinstance(s, Lecture))
            self.assertEqual(s.__str__(), s.title)

        def test_get_upload_to(self):
            s = self.create_lecture()
            self.assertEqual( s.get_upload_to(), 'uploads/E318/CSE2233/lecture-1')
```

I put the field of title for lecture to be a slugfield, so does django put it automatically as a slug ?
I tried the slugfield and it just return the title as "Lecture 1" instead of "lecture-1", or maybe I'm missing something.

So how can I access the foreign keys from the models and test it that the dynamic upload path is working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to access the other models by their foreign keys such as `self.module.programme.code` - to retrieve the code of the programme.